# Python - Very Strange sys.path behavior

Tags: python

The entry for sys.path[0] is `'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode'`.  The Python docs say this should be the working directory of the script.  Any idea what could be going on?

When I run Python from the interactive interpreter and do `import sys; print sys.path[0];` it prints `''` which seems to be right.

But when my Python script is called from a perl script I get the above entry for `sys.path[0]`.

**Other info:**

- I'm running Python 2.7.
- I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit.
- My working directory should be /mnt/galaxyData/custom/MSG_toy
- The perl script and the python script it's calling are located in /mnt/galaxyData/custom/MSG_toy/msg  (That msg directory is a symbolic link if it matters)

Here is everything on sys.path:

```
['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode',
 '/mnt/galaxyData/custom/msg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bx_python-0.7.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqplib-1.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Fabric-1.3.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ssh-1.7.9-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-0.11-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Logbook-0.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml-2.3.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MarkupSafe-0.15-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Paste-1.7.5.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_cjson-1.0.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyOpenSSL-0.13-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyYAML-3.10-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Routes-1.12.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson-2.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Sphinx-1.1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils-0.8.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pygments-1.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/WebHelpers-1.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/WebOb-1.2b2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd-0.7.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.15.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pyrex-0.9.9-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.6.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-11.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/biopython-1.58-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-2.4.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysam-0.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_dateutil-1.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu-1.4.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/anyjson-0.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DendroPy-3.9.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/HTSeq-0.5.3p3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx-1.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.5.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygr-0.8.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysparse-1.2_dev-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2-2.2.4dev_20111114-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2_bioconductor_extensions-0.2.5_dev-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikits.learn-0.8.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikits.statsmodels-0.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy-0.10.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy-0.7.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.8-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py-2.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo-2.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysqlite-2.6.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2-2.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuplot_py-1.8-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydot-1.0.25-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyparsing-1.5.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygooglechart-0.3.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab-2.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bcbio_nextgen-0.3a-py2.7.egg',
 '/mnt/galaxyData/custom/bin/python_libs',
 '/mnt/galaxyData/custom/MSG_toy',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
```

Comment: and `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode` isn't the directory where your script is located (this different from the current working dir, I think you misinterpreted the docs in that regard)?

Comment: What is your Perl script doing to call the Python script? What's the cwd within the Perl script before the call?

Comment: Anyone's allowed to modify `sys.path`; that includes prepending entries when you import a module!

Comment: @Cameron, so you're saying something I import could be messing with sys.path?  That seems possible.  Is there a better way for the script to know which directory it lives in?

Comment: This should do it: `import os; print(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Comment: Yes, I dont think there is any reason to expect that the working directory of the current script will always be the first position in sys.path, since any other script calling your tool can modify the environment. If you really need it, use previous suggestion by @AndiDog to insert it into the 0 index of sys.path

Comment: Thanks everyone.  If anyone wants to post this knowledge as an answer I'll award it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import os; print(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Cred to @AndiDog.

**EDIT:** Also mind the hints in the documentation ([here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) and [here](http://docs.python.org/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_module)) on the availability and value of `__file__`:

> Predefined (writable) attributes: __name__ is the module’s name; __doc__ is the module’s documentation string, or None if unavailable; __file__ is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file. The __file__ attribute is not present for C modules that are statically linked into the interpreter; for extension modules loaded dynamically from a shared library, it is the pathname of the shared library file.
>
> __file__ is set to the name provided by the module loader. If the loader does not make filename information available, this variable is set to None.